# MODIS R Package strsplit error

Tags: r, error, modis

I'm trying to use MODIS to download some spatial data, but I'm not able to do it. When I try to download and process MODIS data with MODIS R package, I get this strange `strsplit` error.

```
 b1 <- runGdal(product = "M.D13A2", begin = Sys.Date() - 30, tileH = 18:19, tileV = 4)
```

Returned:

```
########################
outProj          =  asIn 
pixelSize        =  asIn 
resamplingType   =  near 
Output directory =  C:/*****************************/MOD13A2.061_20210525100758  (no 'job' name specified, generated (date/time based))
########################
Local structure is up-to-date. Using offline information!
Hm, I have to search for the file. Next time provide the full path and I'll be very fast!
Error in strsplit(x, ":") : non-character argument
```

I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: From a new install of MODIS and presumably a clean output directory I get a different error, starting `Downloading structure on 'LAADS' for: MOD13A2.006 \\ ... Error in lns[[select]] : \\ attempt to select less than one element in get1index \\ Error in if (FtpDayDirs[1] == FALSE) { : \\ missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Check package issues and report? https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS/issues